# Find position of vector in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the vector:

```
1 2 3
```

and the matrix:

```
4 1 2 3 5 5 
9 8 7 6 3 1
1 4 7 8 2 3
```

I am trying to find a simple way of locating the vector [1 2 3] in my matrix.

A function returning either coordinates (Ie: (1,2:4)) or a matrix of 1s where there is a match a 0s where there isn't, Ie:

```
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So far, the only function I've found is is 'ismember', which however only tells me if the individual components of the vector appear in the matrix. Suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to search this site first to look for similar questions, this kind of question gets asked a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strfind` with a linearized version of the matrix, and then convert linear indices to subindices. Care should be taken to remove matches of the vector spanning different rows.

```
mat = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2;
       3 0 1 2 3 5 4 4]; %// data
vec = [1 2 3]; %// data

ind = strfind(reshape(mat.',[],1).', vec);
[col row] = ind2sub(fliplr(size(mat)), ind);
keep = col<=size(mat,2)-length(vec)+1; %// remove result split across rows
row = row(keep);
col = col(keep);
```

Result for this example:

```
>> row, col

row =

     1     1     2

col =

     1     4     3
```

meaning the vector appears three times: row 1, col 1;  row 1, col 4;  row 2, col 3.

The result can be expressed in zero-one form as follows:

```
result = zeros(fliplr(size(mat)));
ind_ones = bsxfun(@plus, ind(keep).', 0:numel(vec)-1);
result(ind_ones) = 1;
result = result.';
```

which gives

```
>> result

result =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the starting location of the vector in the matrix is using `colfilt`:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2; ...
        3 0 1 2 3 5 4 4]; % matrix from Luis Mendo
>> T = [1 2 3];
>> colFun = @(x,t) all(x==repmat(t,1,size(x,2)),1);
>> B = colfilt(A,size(T),'sliding',colFun,T(:))
B =
     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

That gives a mask of the center points, which translate to (row,col) coordinates:

```
>> [ii,jj]=find(B);
>> locs = bsxfun(@minus,[ii jj],floor((size(T)-1)/2))
locs =
     1     1
     2     3
     1     4
```